# Unable to get File Name from Content-Disposition

Tags: c#, file-upload, rest

I am working on 'REST Client' which calls a `REST` webservices and get file name in `Content-Disposition` header as `attachment; filename*=utf-8''20200217_152840.jpg`

I have written following code but its not returning the filename

```
 using System.Net.Mime;
 using System.Web;

 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) Req.GetResponse();
 string filenameheader = (response.Headers["Content-Disposition"]);
 ContentDisposition contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(filenameheader);
 string filename = contentDisposition.FileName;
```

This code was working previously when response header was like `attachment; filename='20200217_152840.jpg`

Comment: well your code snipet doesnt do anything to set the filename  property. If you take a look at the docs  create a new contentdisposition simply takes a string that describes the type but doesnt do anything for the rest of the object. so you need to take care to set the filename before you can return it. So you need to take your header and extract the informations and set the propeties on your newly created contentdisposition object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Core REST API for file upload, you can use this code:

```
[HttpPost]  
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.ToString();
}
```

Another way to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    var files = Request.Form.Files;

    string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.ToString();
}
```

You can refer this for more details on different ways of file uploading:
[Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question is not much detailed. I am actually working on REST Client which calls the Rest Webservices, this rest webservices return me file name in Header.

Comment: Is your RESR client also another C# application?  or is it a web application? Can you please update your question with more details?

Comment: Ok, now I can see, your client is a C# application. Is it a .net core application or a standard .net application?